# how to change matplotlib 3d plot to side-view?

Tags: python, matplotlib, projection

If there is arrays of x, y, and z coordinates. I don't mean to show a static 2d plot, which can be drawn by

```
plot(x, y)
```

I mean

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot(x, y, z, label='parametric curve')

plt.show()
```

which matplotlib function can change the view to side-view? So that I can add buttons for the matplotlib GUI, on which when user click, the 3d plot will be drawn as top-view/left-view/... and the user can still use mouse to rotate the plot in a 3d way later, just like what we can do in CAD software.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are looking for the function [`Axes3D.view_init`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.view_init)

> view_init(elev=None, azim=None)
>
> Set the elevation and azimuth of the axes.
>
> This can be used to rotate the axes programatically.
>
> ‘elev’ stores the elevation angle in the z plane. ‘azim’ stores the azimuth angle in the x,y plane.
>
> if elev or azim are None (default), then the initial value is used which was specified in the Axes3D constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what UI toolkit you plan to use. Matplotlib could use multiple backends, among those are file backend, Qt4 backend, Qt5 backend, Wx toolkit backend etc.

If you decide to make UI in python using Qt backend, there is an example how to embed matplotlib plot using Qt backend into Qt canvas: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html

Similar embedding could be done for Wx toolkit. I would also guess you could use matplotlib JS backend like http://mpld3.github.io/, and proceed with making UI in Javascript

Comment: I edited my post. I think the first thing for me is to find the function to change the 3d view to different orthogonal views